# How do I resize a window to full screen in Java?

Tags: java, image, resize, window

I've been working on a game for a class for the last couple of months and didn't realize until I tried to make it a jar file that I have an issue.

When I run the program out of netbeans, it's fine, more or less.

[image: IDE run]

When I make a jar, the window increases in size, beyond what fits on my screen

[image: Jar run]

So I tried to do something in full screen mode, but it doesn't make the contents full screen, just the window

[image: Full Screen run]

I've been making the game with the assumption of the first screen shot, but when I made the jar file, it runs slightly larger, just enough to cut off the bottom of the screen (the fonts also look terrible and the timing is much faster, but one problem at a time). So I thought hey, lets just have some kind of full screen mode and after some looking around I ended up with screenshot 3. Ideally I'd like the game to go full screen and have the images automatically stretch/shrink to fit the window, but every solution I've found thus far only stretches the window itself, not the images in it.

This is what I have to build the window:

```
private void initUI() {

        add(new Board());

        setExtendedState(getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setUndecorated(true);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false); 
        pack(); 
        setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    }
```

I tried using this to make it full screen:

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
setSize(screenSize.width,screenSize.height);
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

EDIT: I tried the suggestion below and ended up with the following which is an improvement, but if I could make that border black somehow it would be better:

[image: Full Screen run 2]

Comment: Move your last 2 images to a site that uses https otherwise they cant be included in the question

Comment: weird, I uploaded them all on the same site...

Comment: First one in imgur and the other 2 are tinypic

Comment: I see that, but I never used imgur to upload the image, which is the weird thing. I used tinypic for all of them

Answer (score 0):

I am doing this with Frame:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
// set properties
frame.setSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
frame.setUndecorated(true);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

It works for me.

Comment: That almost fixes the problem. At least the size stays consistent between jar and IDE runs so that's a step in the right direction. It makes kind of a white background and throws the game atop it, which I guess is fine if there's no better solution. at least it's centered and assets aren't going off the screen. If I can't get the images to resize to fit the screen though, is there a way to at least change the color of that white background to black?